# Passenger+Nginx show custom 500 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I'm using Rails 3.2 with passenger+nginx. I want to display nice custom 500 page when the db server is down. I want to show something when my rails app cannot be started. Here is my nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/store/public;
  error_page   500  /500.html;

  # root
  location / {
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    passenger_use_global_queue on;
  }

}
```

The above configuration doesn't work at all. When it happens, it shows only:

> Internal Server Error (500)

Any idea?

Comment: I would assume that passenger delivers this error page and nginx is not able to intercept it. Have you tried replacing the error page inside of passenger? That might work in this case.

Comment: I can't figure out where is the error page of passenger. Do you know that?

Comment: Unfortunately not as I don't regularly work with Passenger.. I just stumbled over this link, maybe that helps: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phusion-passenger/2KLI8Yqnoaw/lSM7ajjINKMJ

Comment: @Chamnap, did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phusion Passenger author here. Use [passenger_intercept_errors off](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#passenger_intercept_errors).

Answer (score 1):

from the passenger documentation http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerFriendlyErrorPages

`passenger_friendly_error_pages off`

Which can be placed inside the http block, server block or location block, will not show the passenger error for startup failures and I believe link to the nginx supplied 500 error page.

Answer (score 1):

mariow's link led me to the answer.  The error files are in the templates folder.  I use rvm, so my templates folder is at `/home/forest.handford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/passenger-4.0.50/resources/templates/` .  Use `find / -name templates | grep passenger` to find yours.  I'm changing `undisclosed_error.html.template` for my site, as it is the error that occurs when people type an invalid URL .